# Alternatives for a Laravel 4 OpenID consumer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, openid

I'm looking for a **good** OpenID implementation (only consumer) for the Laravel 4 framework to use with a custom enterprise provider at my work.

I a little research i found so far that:

- The [HybridAuth](https://packagist.org/packages/hybridauth/hybridauth) project used by a lot of people is dead ... see [here](https://twitter.com/HybridAuth/status/371026127642320896) and [here](https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth/issues/106)
- The [PHP-OpenID](https://packagist.org/packages/openid/php-openid) project seems old and lack of documentation at least in the github page.
- Ohter kind of projects like [oauth-4-laravel](https://packagist.org/packages/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel) looks really awesome but in the docs i don't see any support for generic OpenID (corect me if i'm wrong) so is not a good option this time.

So the question is:

Is there any good library to use that implements OpenID on Laravel 4 ?? 
By good i mean still alive (fixing issues and support) and with enough documentation to make an integration with Laravel 4.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently looking into **Mozilla Persona** for user login/logout in my projects.
Maybe it's not exactly what you are looking for, but still is pretty nice.

site: https://login.persona.org/about

package: https://packagist.org/packages/jyggen/persona (including Laravel provider)

Comment: Persona is abandoned by Mozilla, by lack of use. Furthermore, the question isn't about product recommendation, but about OpenID.